# Pass object from tableview to destination with revealviewcontroller in between

Tags: swift, uitableview, swrevealviewcontroller

I am trying to pass an object from my tableview to the detail view. I am using the revealviewcontroller framework to have a slide out menu. Therefore I need to create a segue from the tableview to the revealviewcontroller and from here another one to the final detailviewcontroller.

That is why I can´t set the object in the detail view - any idea how to do so?

This is the used code:

```
if segue.identifier == "communityDetailSegue" {

  // Get the cell that generated this segue.
  if let selectedCommunityCell = sender as ? UITableViewCell {

    let destination = segue.destinationViewController as!CommunityViewController

    if let communityIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(selectedCommunityCell) {

      destination.community = self.communitiesOfCurrentUser[communityIndex.row]
      print(self.communitiesOfCurrentUser[communityIndex.row].name)
    }

  }
}
```

And this is the exception.

> Could not cast value of type 'SWRevealViewController' (0x10027b9f0) to 'CommunityViewController'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error because the segue's destination VC is the `SWRevealViewController` and not the `CommunityViewController`.

One way of solving your problem would be to pass the value in two steps:

First, in `prepareForSegue()` you pass the value to the SWRevealViewController (you'll need a subclass for this one, e.g. `MyRevealViewController`):

```
if segue.identifier == "communityDetailSegue" {

  // Get the cell that generated this segue.
  if let selectedCommunityCell = sender as ? UITableViewCell {

    let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! MyRevealViewController

    if let communityIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(selectedCommunityCell) {

      destination.community = self.communitiesOfCurrentUser[communityIndex.row]
      print(self.communitiesOfCurrentUser[communityIndex.row].name)
    }
  }
}
```

Then, in `MyRevealViewController`you can pass the value as soon as it is set:

```
class MyRevealViewController : SWRevealViewController {

    // Let's assume this is the outlet to your final VC:
    IBOutlet let communityViewController: CommunityViewController!

    var community: YourCommunityType {
       didSet {
          if let communityVC = self.communityViewController {
              communityVC.community = self.community
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I followed your advise - Now I get "Could not cast value of type 'SWRevealViewController' (0x2235004) to 'MyRevealViewController' (0x11b8fc)." Any other things I would need to do when implementing the subclass?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to set MyRevealViewController as the class for your ViewController in Interface Builder instead of SWRevealViewController

Comment: Needed to add some init methods for the view, but it works now. Thanks a lot for your help on this!

Comment: Need to get back to this - I can´t send the object to the 2nd VC. Any chance you can elaborate on that "IBOutlet" in MyRevealVC? I think this is what I don´t get here. Thanks